# Difference between CXF and JAX-WS

Tags: jax-ws, cxf

I am pretty new to web services. I am not able to find the difference between JAX-WS and CXF.

According to my understanding, JAX-WS is the specification provided by java and CXF is the implementation.

Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Here is the similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11566609/difference-between-jax-ws-axis2-cxf

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, you are right.

JAX-WS is Java specification for SOAP based web services. CXF is its implementation by Apache.

JAX-WS reference implementation is JAX-WS RI, by Oracle. Latest one is JAX-WS RI 2.2.5