# How cxf and jax-ws are related

Tags: jax-ws, cxf

I have created web-service using `jax-ws` and used it.
How `cxf` and `jax-ws` are related? 
If we can create and consume web service using `jax-ws`, Why we need `cxf` ?
Can someone give some pointers for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please refer  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11566609/difference-between-jax-ws-axis2-cxf)  and  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9700715/difference-between-cxf-and-jax-ws) . CXF is implementation of JAX-WS. Hence what ever your JAX-WS code, you can use in CXF. CXF provides more features like interceptors, spring integration etc. In configuration file you can use cxf or jax-ws features by specifying corresponding namespaces.

Answer (score 0):

I have recently completed the web service implementation with JAX-WS using reference implementation apache-cxf. And I found with CXF - integration with Spring is very easy. Moreover, It provides various features like:

1. Customization of Logging features
2. Inbound and Outbound interceptor
3. Application Level security
4. Easy Exception handling using custom Fault.

For more detail, if you want, please checkout this link:
http://predic8.com/axis2-cxf-jax-ws-comparison.htm

And, I read above link, its preety helpful for me.

Thanks !